# Has any girl trainer won the league in Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon

Has any girl trainer won the league in Pokémon or do girls and boys go in separate leagues?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should have been asked in https://anime.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mattiav27  ***THAT IS NOT A VALID CLOSE REASON. ANIME IS 100% ON TOPIC HERE.***

Answer (score 3):

In the core series games, the player character wins the league and can be chosen by the player as male or female (except in RGBYGS, where the character is male). Before the player wins the league, it has a champion who is in some cases female (Cynthia, Iris, Diantha).

In the anime both sexes compete in a common league, which so far is only known to have been won by males (an unknown male in Kanto, plus several named males in the later leagues). However, contests often have female winners, while showcases only have female entrants.